# How can I load a .env file in a nodejs CLI application in the package.json bin

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, .env

I have a Nodejs CLI (command line) application that works fine but I want to use a config.env file with secrets in it. Node 20.6.0 has added support for .env without using e.g. DOTENV

I tried to add the .env in my package.json in the bin that has the command in a Node CLI application but it does not work:

```
{
"name": "myapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "app.js",
"type": "module",
"bin": {
"mycli": "--env-file=config.env /apps/app.js"
},
"keywords": [],...}
```

I tried "mycli": "--env-file=config.env /apps/app.js" and
"mycli": "--env-file config.env /apps/app.js"

but running mycli in terminal does not load the .env
I use node 20.8.0 on MacOS Sonoma

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: what's your situation for running a bin script in this way?

Comment: You can change this to use the `scripts` command.

Comment: In this way I can use nodejs and Javascript to make and run scripts instead of using bash, so for me JavaScript all the way: client-side, server-side, in the database (MongoDB) and for scripting 

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
Instead of adding env link in the package.json at the bin, it just needs to be added on top of your .js file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --env-file=config.env
```

this works!